# Программно сгенерировать скрипт для всех обьектов в базе

Tags: c#, sql-server

В MS SQL есть инструмент генерации скриптов базы (правый клик на базе, затем Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> all tables + в настройках advanced заменить Types of data to script с Schema only на Data only).

Я пользуюсь этим инструментом, чтобы сделать резервную копию базы с продакшн сервера: это appharbor, я не могу сделать бекап локально и забрать файл с сервера.

А можно ли запускать этот инструмент автоматически, программным способом, например из c#? Хочу перейти к регулярным резервным копиям по расписанию, а не делать изредка по настроению копии "на всякий случай".

На сервере стоит SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Все таблички в БД можно получить [так](https://tym32167.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/blog-post.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Генерация скрипта - не самый удобный вариант для экспорта базы вместе с данными.

Есть утилита sqlpackage, которая позволяет экспортировать/импортировать базу в формате bacpac. Это [стандартный способ для импорта/экспорта баз для Azure SQL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/01/31/using-sqlpackage-to-import-or-export-azure-sql-db/), где нет прямого доступа к серверу:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:tcp:<ServerName>.database.windows.net,1433 /sdn:<DatabaseName> /su:<UserName> /sp:<Password> /tf:<TargetFile> /p:Storage=File
```

Соответствующие пункты в контекстном меню в SMSS - Import / Export Data Tier Application.

Для импорта используется bulk insert, что в разы быстрее простой построчной вставки.

Comment: Отличная тулзовина, не знал о ней. Спасибо!

Comment: Тоже не знал, а она штатная оказывается. Галка на этом ответе, так как закрывает метапотребность, а не заявленную. Проверил - работает с apphabror. На второй ответ добавлю конкурсные баллы.

Answer (score 5):

Для этого надо воспользоваться [SQL Server Management Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017)
Пример кода на C# для генерации скриптов можно посмотреть по [ссылке](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/)
Сам использую скрипт на Powershell - [ссылка на готовый скрипт](https://gist.github.com/cheynewallace/9558179)
В вашем случае придется добавить в примеры параметр для включения данных в экспорт `ScriptingOptions.ScriptData = True` [подробнее о параметре](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.scriptdata.aspx)