# SQL Server - понижение версии бд с 2014 на 2012

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Необходимо развернуть резервную копию базы данных 2014 на Sql Server 2012. Резервную копию более новой бд нельзя развернуть на старом сервере, поэтому я сгенерировал скрипт через `Tasks->Generate Scripts`, вес которого превышает 912МБ. Его нельзя запустить через SSMS, возникает ошибка `Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program`.

При запуске скрипта через `sqlcmd` возникает ошибка `Syntax error at line 66678` независимо от того, что находится в строке под номером 66678. В самом скрипте ошибок нет.

Как мне выполнить скрипт создания базы данных на сервере старой версии?

Comment: Нашел полный дубликат, на который я отвечал раньше: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873087/. Рабочее решение без сторонних утилит - через  Import / Export Data Tier Application. К сожалению, ваш вопрос не получается закрыть как дубликат, т.к. за него объявлен конкурс.

Comment: Похожий вопрос, с тем же решением - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815332/

Comment: @PashaPash первый вариант не работает по причинам, изложенным в вопросе, второй падает с ошибками SQL71562 при переносе хранимых процедур, так как они ссылаются на внешние объекты

Comment: первый вариант у вас тоже упадет с ошибкой SQL71562, как и любое другое переселение - я сомневаюсь, что вы сможете корректно поднять базу без предварительного переноса внешних объектов.

Comment: если там ссылки на ту же базу через 3-part имя - то попробуйте https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ssdt/windows-azure-importexport-service-and-external-references/

Comment: @PashaPash база данных корректно переносится через Tasks->Generate Scripts, если сократить количество экспортируемых записей (соответственно размер скрипта), но это недопустимо.

Comment: на старом сервере попробуйте сделать бд с режимом совместимости 2012го сервера. потом сделайте экспорт/импорт из 2014й бд в 2012ю. и потом уже ее забекапте/восстановите.

Answer (score 0):

Разверните бекап на 2014 сервере, а данные перенесите на нужный сервер либо через встроенное средство Export/Import, но тогда придется восстанавливать все ключи и все такое... либо воспользуйтесь `ESF Migration Tollkit`, который на сколько я помню, умеет это делать.

Answer (score 0):

> Как мне выполнить скрипт создания базы данных на сервере старой версии?

Ошибка `Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.` может появляться из-за слишком большого объема скрипта.

Можно вручную разбить скрипт на части размером около 1 МБ и выполнять из поочередно. Разбивать нужно по разделителю. У SSMS, если не путаю, это `GO`